# Complexity and approximability of maximum edge biclique problem on co-comparability graphs

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, graph-algorithms, approximation-algorithms

A subgraph $H$ of a given graph $G$ is called a biclique of $G$ if $H$ is a complete bipartite graph.  Given a graph $G$, finding a maximum edge biclique is known to be NP-complete ([Peeters](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0166218X03003330), *Discrete Applied Mathematics* 131, pages 651-654, 2003).

In fact, it is also known that it is unlikely we can obtain an $n^{\delta}$-approximation for this problem in polynomial time, for some constant $\delta > 0$ ([Feige](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/summary?doi=10.1.1.3.8586), STOC 2002; Goerdt and Lanka, ECCC 2004; Ambuhl, Mastrolilli, and Svensson SICOMP 2011).  These results hold even when $G$ is bipartite.

I was wondering whether any results are known for finding the maximum edge biclique in *co-comparability graphs*.  There are several equivalent definitions of a co-comparability graph.  One of them is a graph whose vertices are the elements of a partial order, and the edges are given by pairs of elements that are incomparable in the partial order.

Specific questions:

(1) Is the maximum edge biclique problem polynomially solvable for co-comparability graphs?

(2) If no polynomial time optimal algorithm is known, what is the best approximation algorithm known?

Comment: Just an observation: the co-comparability graph is perfect by Dilworh's theorem. Maybe this can help.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  Unfortunately, since bipartite graphs are perfect, the $n^\delta$ hardness mentioned above applies to perfect graphs.

Comment: Good point, I had not noticed the hardness holds for bipartite graphs.